# Is there a way to get different sizes of the Windows system icons in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, icons

In particular I'd like to be able to get the small (16 x 16) icons at runtime.

I tried this:

```
new Icon(SystemIcons.Error, SystemInformation.SmallIconSize)
```

Which supposedly "attempts to find a version of the icon that matches the requested size", but it's still giving me a 32 x 32 icon. I also tried:

```
Size iconSize = SystemInformation.SmallIconSize;
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(iconSize.Width, iconSize.Height);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    g.DrawIcon(SystemIcons.Error, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, iconSize));
}
```

But that just scales the 32 x 32 icon down into an ugly 16 x 16.

I've considered just pulling icons out of the VS Image Library, but I really want them to vary dynamically with the OS (XP icons on XP, Vista icons on Vista, etc.). I'm willing to P/Invoke if that's what it takes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wound up P/Invoking. It turns out that both [LoadIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648072(VS.85).aspx) and [LoadImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045(v=VS.85).aspx) exhibit the same (flawed, IMO) behavior as `SystemIcons`. But [SHGetStockIconInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762205(VS.85).aspx), which is available on Vista and later, works as expected, returning the small, official, designer-crafted icons that I've been looking for.

On XP and earlier, I'm falling back to using the small icons provided in the VS Image Library.

If you're thinking about P/Invoking `SHGetStockIconInfo` yourself, I recommend taking a look at the [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) to see how.

Comment: do you think you could provide code sample for this solution including that non-Vista fallback?

Answer (score 14):

You have to scale them yourself.  The SystemIcons, as you found out, only have 32x32.  You can easily scale them to 16 or 48 as needed.  Use interpolation to get a nice bicubic resize.  We've done this many times successfully to create very nice looking 16x16 versions and it works fine whether running XP or Vista or 7.

```
Size iconSize = SystemInformation.SmallIconSize;
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(iconSize.Width, iconSize.Height);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))   
{
    g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.DrawImage(SystemIcons.Error.ToBitmap(), new Rectangle(Point.Empty, iconSize));   
}

Icon smallerErrorIcon = Icon.FromHandle(bitmap.GetHicon());
```

Be sure to check out the MSDN example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.gethicon.aspx), especially their use of the `DestroyIcon` method to clean up the handle when you're done.

Comment: You're right. DrawIcon doesn't seems to take in account the interpolation mode. Replace DrawIcon by DrawBitmap, use SystemIcons.Error.ToBitmap() to transform your icon in bmp, and you get a nice result.

Comment: Now that you've redrawn the icon image in a smaller size, how do you get an `Icon` object from the code above?

Comment: MSDN has a good example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.gethicon.aspx). Basically, call `GetHicon` on the newly made Bitmap and then you can use the static `Icon.FromHandle` method. Pay attention to their use of the external `DestroyIcon` method. Working with handles directly feels hacky in C# and requires proper cleanup but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for this constructor overload says:

> *"Initializes a new instance of the `Icon` class and attempts to find a version of the icon that matches the requested size.*
>
> *"If a version cannot be found that exactly matches the size, the closest match is used.
>   **If the `original` parameter is an `Icon` that has a single size, this method only creates a duplicate icon**."*

I think that this icon has only one size (32×32); and the only way to get different sizes is to scale this icon to your size, as in your example.

Comment: These icons definitely exist at a smaller size. If I can't access them through SystemIcons, that's fine, but I'd like to know if there's a way that works.

Comment: Sorry, could I ask, how do you know that these icons exist in smaller size?

Comment: @PavelBelousov if you check **C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll** using some icon editor capable of extracting icon resources, you will see all sizes and color depths of these standard icons. Available sizes are 16x16, 32x32, 48x48.